# Firebase experiments count limit

Tags: firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config

Currently in firebase console for my project I have 2 remote config experiments(running), 4 notification experiments(running), 3 remote config experiments drafts and 0 completed experiments. When i am pressing to start one more remote config experiment, firebase console syas "Error starting experiment: Too many running experiments".

What is the limit of firebase experiments (remote config/notification) that can be active?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Firebase documentation for Create Firebase Remote Config Experiments with A/B Testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/abtest-config#start_an_experiment):

> To start your experiment, click Start Experiment. **You can run up to 24 experiments per project at a time.**

Answer (score 4):

Firebase supports now up to 24 simultaneous experiments

reference link:
[firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/abtest-config#start_an_experiment)